# Unit test that ensures method A called after method B

Tags: unit-testing

I have a code which interacts with some object and then should call finish() method on it.

```
void completeTransaction(PaymentTransaction transaction) {  
    recordTransaction(transaction.getId());

    transaction.finish();
}
```

PaymentTransaction is some third-party class which behaviour after `finish()` is undefined — it may throw an exception or just fail silently.

I need to write a unit test which passes then and only then:

1. `recordTransaction(transaction.getId())` called
2. `transaction.finish()` called
3. `transaction.finish()` called *after* `recordTransaction(transaction.getId())`

Test satisfying the above conditions should prohibit code like this:

```
void completeTransaction(PaymentTransaction transaction) {
   transaction.finish();
   recordTransaction(transaction.getId()); //oops
}
```

Test case for the first condition:

```
void testCompleteTransaction_TransactionRecorded() {
    completeTransaction(transactionMock);
    // assert that recordTransaction(transaction.getId()) 
    // called with correct argument
```

completeTransaction(PaymentTransaction transaction)
    }
For the second one:

```
void testCompleteTransaction_TransactionCompleted() {
    completeTransaction(transactionMock);
    // assert that transaction.finish() called
}
```

I wonder how can I enforce the 3rd condition via test case.

Comment: What testing framework(s) are involved. What language is this? Can you show your existing tests for 1 and 2?

Comment: You are missing some explanation: As long as recordTransacation does not create an Thread it is finished when you return from the call.  Do you want to wait for another Thread inside recordTransaction() ?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: This code written in some made-up language to separate the problem from language-specific details.

Comment: @AlexWien: No, all this is just about calling methods in a correct order.

Comment: I edited my question to emphasize important points and make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass in a fake `PaymentTransaction` that overrides `finish()` and `getId()` such that `finish()` throws an exception if some internal flag isn't set when `getId()` is called.

```
public class FakePaymentTransaction {
    private bool _getIdWasCalled = false;

    public override void finish () {
        if (!_getIdWasCalled) {
            throw new Exception ("getId wasn't called first!");
        }
    }

    public override /* your return type */ getId() {
        _getIdWasCalled = true;
        // Some other logic to return your specified return type
    }
}
```

Now when you pass it into your SUT, you will see if the calls were made in the right order.

Comment: Thank you. I guess there isn't more lightweight solution.

Comment: I would disagree. This is a pretty lightweight solution. You're controlling the inputs of the SUT so you can define exactly what's going on inside. There's not really a "magical" way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a mock that can verify the order of calls was as expected.  You can roll your own for the specific case as suggested in James D'Angelo's answer or you could create a more generic one  that works similarly.

Or you can use facilities supplied by a good mocking framework.

Mockito has, for example, an [InOrder](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.4/javadoc/org/mockito/InOrder.html) verifier that can verify the order of calls of mocked methods from a single mock or multiple mocks.

Comment: Agreed. Since there was no language indicated with the OP, I didn't feel I could give a more language/framework specific answer.

Comment: @JamesD'Angelo:  Your answer was fine, and I voted it up.  Just thought a note that some frameworks supply help might also be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the up-vote. I didn't mean to seem like I was being defensive. Just wish more info would have been presented so we could give a better answer.  =)

Answer (score 0):

Your test case makes no sense:

Methods are called in the order you  have them in the code:
In an Unit test you should not only call some methods, you should test for a correct result.

but if you want to have some fun:

```
public testNonsenseTest() {
     int i  = 0;
     PaymentTransaction transaction = new PaymentTransaction();
     int transactionId = transaction.getId());
     recordTransaction(transactionId);
     i++;
     assertEquals(1, i);
     transaction.finish();
     i++;
     assertEquals(2, i);

}
```

Comment: I think they make sense in terms of white box unit testing: I define what code expected to do. The result here is to record transaction and make sure it's finished.

Comment: At least it is usefull, that you can debug into, when starting the test case. And you cann test that transactionId is different from another transactinid

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to make actual calls in my test cases. That was your point?

Comment: Without knowning your code its is very difficult. What happens if an transactipn si not scuessfuly?ß Does it throw an excdeption? If yes, than a test similar to mine makes sense, it shows, that at least the methdos can be callesd whithout exception.

Comment: What is the return Value of recordTranaction() Is it an boolean or void. if boolean: you could do assertTrue(recordTransaction(trasacationId));

Comment: Ah you want to write an test case that shows that a wrong oder (You wrote "Opps") leads to an error? But then tell me which errror occurs when you do it as described in "Oops"

Comment: Or is this a homework in theretical informatik, dealing with logic languages. It seems not to be a real code

Comment: Well, something _bad_ happens. For example, `getId` returns wrong id.